# Object is not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make a transfer code for my player game object
but it didn't work. I don know why, but I think maybe there is a problem with "Lerp" part. What is the problem?

```
public class Player_Ctrl : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float movespeed = 3.0f;

    private void Update () 
    {
        Vector3 PlayerPos = transform.position;
        Vector3 NextPos   = transform.position;

        if (Input.touchCount != 1) return;

        float ChangingPos = this.transform.position.x * movespeed;
        NextPos.x = ChangingPos;
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) return;

            if (hit.collider.tag == "LEFTSIDE" || hit.collider.tag == "RIGHTSIDE")
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(PlayerPos, NextPos, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never write the same code twice, like how you just did. You should've either refactored the if statements into a function and call that function, or do what I did and use the or `||` so that the if blocks will fire if either side of the `||` is true.

Comment: Also, you should extract the values `"LEFTSIDE"` and `"RIGHTSIDE"` as `const` values, like this: `public const string LEFTSIDE = "LEFTSIDE"` and use that variable instead. You can't change the value of `const` members and the compiler will optimize around that fact. The benefit is that if you decieded to change `"LEFTSIDE"` to be `"LeftSide"` you only have to change it in one place and it gets changed in all its usages, instead of having to trace down all the places you used it.

Comment: thanks for the advice. im new at programing world so good advice like this very helpful for me! thank you!

Comment: Of course, we were all noobs at one point (: Also, you don't need to use `this` unless needed. The most common time to use it is when you have a private field `foo` (because its private, its lowercase by convention) and a parameter `foo` (because its a parameter, its lowercase by convention). The compiler won't know which `foo` is which, so you use `this.foo`, for the field and just `foo` for the parameter, like this: `public MyConstructor(int foo) => this.foo = foo;` Other than that, you don't need `this`

Answer (score 3):

Lerp is a function that interpolates between two positions, using the third argument, which is a value between 0 and 1.

You use Time.deltaTime as your third argument. So if your Position and NextPosition are always the same, (And Time.deltaTime will be roughly the same if you have a constant frame rate), then the output of the Lerp will always be the same.

Furthermore, this piece of code:

```
float ChangingPos = this.transform.position.x * movespeed;
```

probably doesn't do what you want it to do. This will take a fraction of your current position, and set that as the next position.

You probably want to move your character with move speed, but in a smooth manner. If so, I would recommend setting a `RigidBody` on your Player `GameObject`, and use forces on the `RigidBody` instead. This will work better, especially if you want to do anything pseudo physically at some point.

So try something like (after you attach the rigid body as a component):

```
//In start:
_rigidBody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();

//In update:
if(_YOUR_CONDITION_){
  _rigidBody.AddForce(Vector3.right * movespeed / Time.deltaTime);
}
```